# How do I graphically represent FFT output?

Tags: python, graphics, scipy, fft, complex-numbers

In the Python IDLE:

```
>>> from scipy.fftpack import fft

>>> fft([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

array([ 28.+0.j, -4.+9.65685425j,
        -4.+4.j, -4.+1.65685425j,
        -4.+0.j, -4.-1.65685425j,
        -4.-4.j, -4.-9.65685425j ])
```

In the above code, I have used one of scipy's FFT functions. The output is an array of complex numbers. How do I represent these complex numbers graphically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've usually seen these things represented as power spectra:  -- e.g. plot the result of [`np.absolute`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) of your data.  Sometimes you'll also see a plot with 2 traces -- one trace for the real part and one trace for the imaginary part.  On the [Wikipedia page for Fourier Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), they show plots of the real part an the imaginary part side-by-side.  It all depends on what you're looking for ...

Comment: Usually a logarithmic scale on the y axis aswell.

Comment: @wim -- I think that depends pretty significantly on the data being analyzed.  If you have a more or less monochromatic signal, you might only see a few dominant frequencies and not care about the others ...